# Blender 3.1 Eevee Material Override gone?

Tags: materials

in older Blender Versions there was a way to create a Material Override in Eevee in the layer properties tab. However in Blender 3.1 it's gone - or I cant't find it anymore. Is there I new spot to look for it, or a new process of doing material overrides?

Thank you for any help and regards

Tomas

Comment: As far as I know, Material Override has always been a 3rd party addon.  I believe [this version](https://github.com/Korchy/blender_eevee_materials_override) is the one people mostly use.

Comment: I think it was a Cycles feature only, in the View Layer Properties panel > Override

Comment: Hey there, thank you very much for your replies - you are right, it's a cyles feature! I intuitively remembered it to be possible in Eevee too, but that's not the case unfortunately. Best regards and all the best!