simple chracter shape - newbie
Im very new to Blender (3D), but i need simple body shapes for use in a body shape catalog. I managed to find the "make human" app where i can style what i need and export them for use in blender. But what i need is a very simple gray body as depicted in the image (without clothes or surface details shape) for use in photoshop. How do i export this as a PNG with a transparent background. Thank you for your input and help. Jan


For the transparent background, enable Film > Transparent in the render properties tab (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1303/107598). Cycles has an option in the render settings to override all materials (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/265273/107598) For Eevee, try the Materials Override add-on for Eevee.

Press N to expand the right side panel, click on the camera icon to see through the camera, click on camera name in the upper right list to select it, use the transform values to move the camera in the desired place (Location and rotation).
In the properties window (Bottom right), render tab, choose "Transparent" as film.

At the top of the render properties, choose "Workbench" as render engine, set samples to 32, and Studio lights, then press F12 to render the image.

When done, press Shift Alt S (or menu Image > Save as), choose a location, select PNG as format and RGBA as channels and press Save as Image button.


And finally...
You can use Viewport Rendering to do this.
Setup:
Set the output file format on the OutputProperties tab:

Set the background to Transparent under RenderProperties > Film.

You can change the shading/lighting on your model by clicking the Shading dropdown and then clicking the Lighting orb. Select the look you require.
Also Click the ViewportOverlays icon to remove all the overlays.

To render the image use the View > ViewportRenderImage menu.

On the RenderResult screen, use the Image > Save menu to save your image.

Result:

